# Jupyter server on Kubernetes - Can access pod's port from port forwarding but not from service NodePort

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, jupyter-lab

I have instantiated a pod and service with the following YAML configurations:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: jupyter-pod
  labels:
    app: jupyter-pod
spec:
  serviceAccountName: spark-driver
  containers:
  - name: jupyter-pod
    image: spark-k8s-jupyter:v3.5.0
    imagePullPolicy: Never
    command: ["jupyter", "lab", "--ip", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "9000"]
    tty: true
    stdin: true
  restartPolicy: Always
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: jupyter-pod
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: jupyter-pod
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 9000  # The port that the service will serve on.
      targetPort: 9000  # The target port on the pod(s) to forward to.
```

When I use `kubectl port-forward pod/jupyter-pod 9000:9000` I can access the page in my browser but not just with the service, what can be causing this? I've tried both the the pod's IP's and localhost and several ports but to no avail.

Some commands I ran trying to find out what's wrong:

```
kubectl get endpoints -A
NAMESPACE              NAME                                 ENDPOINTS                                           AGE
default                jupyter-service                      10.244.0.147:9000                                   4m30s


k describe service jupyter-service                                                                                                                                                          
Name:                     jupyter-service                                                                                                                                                     
Namespace:                default                                                                                                                                                             
Labels:                   <none>                                                                                                                                                              
Annotations:              <none>                                                                                                                                                              
Selector:                 app=jupyter-pod                                                                                                                                                     
Type:                     NodePort                                                                                                                                                            
IP Family Policy:         SingleStack                                                                                                                                                         
IP Families:              IPv4                                                                                                                                                                
IP:                       10.106.188.89                                                                                                                                                       
IPs:                      10.106.188.89                                                                                                                                                       
Port:                     <unset>  9000/TCP                                                                                                                                                   
TargetPort:               9000/TCP                                                                                                                                                            
NodePort:                 <unset>  31175/TCP                                                                                                                                                  
Endpoints:                10.244.0.147:9000                                                                                                                                                   
Session Affinity:         None                                                                                                                                                                
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster                                                                                                                                                             
Events:                   <none> 


k get service
NAME                TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
jupyter-pod         NodePort    10.103.70.121   <none>        9000:30192/TCP   9s
```

Edit:

I solved it by specifying `hostNetwork: true`, but I don't believe this is best practice so I'd still appreciate if someone could solve this without using hostNetwork.

Comment: You should use IP returned from command `minikube ip` and port `30192`

Comment: @zori I tried every combination of IPs and ports, cluster IP, endpoint IP and local host and 9000/30192/31175 ports and none load.

Comment: What is your system?

Comment: @zori Ubuntu 22.04. Running Minikube 1.32.0 with Docker VM and DNS addons.

Comment: Is `ping` on ip from `minikube ip` working? you can also try `minikube tunnel`, looks like system setup issue not deployments

Comment: @zori yes it's working. I imagine it can be a Minikube configuration but don't know how to test it anymore, tried nmap but it can't find any open ports,

Comment: I tried to test it on my local (but I have WSL only) when I do `nmap -p- $(minikube ip)` I got `31742/tcp open  unknown` that matches output from `kubectl get svc jupyter-pod`, then I did `curl $(minikube ip):31742` and everything is working, maybe this will give you some sight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to set nodePort in Specs, here the working version:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: jupyter-pod
  name: jupyter-pod-svc
  namespace: default
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 9000
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 9000
    nodePort: 31200
  selector:
    app: jupyter-pod
  type: NodePort
```